# Is it better to build a hash table from an existing array than to create a hash table first then insert all the elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

Are there any implementations which would pick several hash functions in a universal hashing and try these functions to reduce the total collisions to an acceptable level and return the best result with the least collisions ?

If there is ,building a hash table from an existing array is much reliable than creating a hash table first then insert all the elements ,isn't it ?

The following paragraphs are from *introduction to algorithms*.

"If a malicious adversary chooses the keys to be hashed by some fixed hash function,then the adversary can choose n keys that all hash to the same slot, yielding an average retrieval time of ‚.n/. Any fixed hash function is vulnerable to such terrible worst-case behavior; the only effective way to improve the situation is to choose the hash function randomly in a way that is independent of the keys that are actually going to be stored. This approach, called universal hashing, can yield provably good performance on average, no matter which keys the adversary chooses.

In universal hashing, at the beginning of execution we select the hash function
at random from a carefully designed class of functions. As in the case of quicksort,randomization guarantees that no single input will always evoke worst-case behavior. Because we randomly select the hash function, the algorithm can behave differently on each execution, even for the same input, guaranteeing good
average-case performance for any input. Returning to the example of a compiler’s
symbol table, we find that the programmer’s choice of identifiers cannot now cause consistently poor hashing performance. Poor performance occurs only when the compiler chooses a random hash function that causes the set of identifiers to hash poorly, but the probability of this situation occurring is small and is the same for any set of identifiers of the same size."

Comment: The behaviour described at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html as "In order to avoid this worst-case behavior, the calculation of the hash value done by qHash() can be salted by a random seed, that nullifies the attack's extent. This seed is automatically generated by QHash once per process, and then passed by QHash as the second argument of the two-arguments overload of the qHash() function." can be a pain in the neck as programs that store QHash derived maps make it very difficult to compare the result of two successive runs of the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the keys in advance, you can use [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) to avoid any collisions. So, if you have all the elements somewhere (as in your example, in an array), and there won't be new inserts, then sure, you can do a lot better.

The thing is, in real apps, keys usually come and go. The table is constantly changing.

I don't know about implementations, but as always it boils down to *trade-offs*. You're trying to trade extra safety for quick lookups, and you'll pay with extra code complexity and slowdown and a potentially costly insert that will recreate the hash when there are lot of collisions. But do you really need that safety? And if you have a lot of collisions, why don't you simply increase the size of the table?

> reduce the total collisions to an acceptable level

The chances of a lot of collisions are really really small (with a good implementation that keeps the table not to dense) and you already defended the algorithm against malicious inputs (as the attacker doesn't know how to abuse keys). For real life applications this is already way better than an "acceptable level".

Comment: You might get some pathological situations if the same code is used at the heart of two communicating applications, or if one application finds that it suddenly needs to reprocess everything that fell into a given hash bucket in the past year.